# docfx doesn't work when I update .NET framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docfx

I am trying to use docfx to create documentation for a library. I need to use at least docfx version 2.18.3 because I need to create pdf documentation. Whenever I try to build the solution, docfx throws a warning that says "no metadata is generated.

My original library was .NET version 4.5.2, but I tried upgrading it to versions 4.6 and 4.6.1 so that it's compatible with docfx version 2.18.3. I have even tried to update my project to .NET 4.7.2 and use it with the latest version of docfx, but that threw even more errors. I am using docfx as a NuGet package with visual studio 2015.

I am expecting docfx to throw no errors or warnings when the project is built, and for my documentation to be generated in the _sites folder. So far, the _sites/api folder generated is empty and I receive the previously mentioned warning: "no metadata is generated."

Answer (score 0):

I attempted executing docfx from command line rather than from visual studio and it worked!